# OrmLite DataType.BYTE_ARRAY Data too long for column

Tags: java, ormlite

I am struggling with inserting a blob, using MySQL. I notice ORMLite creates the corresponding column with DataType     BLOB, while I require a LONGBLOB, since I get an exception thrown telling me

> Data too long for column

I annotate the column:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY)
```

What options are left, besides running a rawQuery when creating the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh ok, I got this. 
I have to add the following:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY, columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
```